# message model and user model

Tags: php, laravel

code of message model

```
<?php

namespace App;    
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Message extends Model
{
    protected $table="Message";     
}
```

code of user model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;    
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model implements Authenticatable
{
    use \Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;    
    protected $table="NewUser";       
}
```

Comment: Can you post code of your 'new_form' view?

Comment: <img src="\upload\{{$detail->image}}" height="100px" width="100px">
{{$detail->username}}<br/>
{{$detail->email}}
<form action="/store/{{$detail->id}}" method="post">
{!!csrf_field()!!}
<input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="title" required><br/>
<textarea rows="4" cols="4" name="post" class="form-control" placeholder="post" required></textarea><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit">
</form>

Comment: <img src="\upload\{{$detail->image}}" height="100px" width="100px">
{{$detail->username}}
{{$detail->email}}
<form action="/store/{{$detail->id}}" method="post">
{!!csrf_field()!!}
<input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="title" required><br/>
<textarea rows="4" cols="4" name="post" class="form-control" placeholder="post" required></textarea><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit">
</form>

Comment: @deepaksharma You should edit your question to add your view code

Answer (score 0):

The message is not displayed because you didn't include it to your blade template. The working solution should be like this:

```
<img src="\upload\{{$detail->image}}" height="100px" width="100px">

{{$detail->username}}

<br/>

{{$detail->email}}

<br>

@foreach($messages as $message)    
    {{$message->body}}
@endforeach

<form action="/store/{{$detail->id}}" method="post">
    {!!csrf_field()!!}
    <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="title" required>
    <br/>
    <textarea rows="4" cols="4" name="post" class="form-control" placeholder="post" required></textarea>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit">
</form>
```

Of course change "body" with whatever field you have in messsages table in DB.

**EDIT:**

You are forwarding same ID to fetch users and their messages.

```
public function getId($id)
{

    $data['detail']=User::find($id) AND  $data['messages']=Message::find($id); 

    return view('new_form',$data);
}
```

Once you define the right model relationship, you should do something like this:

```
public function getId($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id)

    $data['detail']=$user AND  $data['messages']=$user->messages() 

    return view('new_form',$data);
}
```

Your User.php should have the relationship as [Ketav Chotaliya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5408928/ketav-chotaliya) suggested:

```
public function messages()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Message');
}
```

This should work if your message model is called `Message.php`, for everything else, rewrite accordingly

Comment: getting error: Trying to get property of non-object (View: /opt/lampp/htdocs/a/resources/views/new_form.blade.php)

Comment: message is getting inserted but not getting displayed

Comment: what do you mean "getting inserted"? Can you edit your post on what you get when you do return $data in your getId method?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not getting your point exactly.

If you are facing problem in JOIN two tables than here is the solution.

You can directly get JOINED data without JOIN Query IF you set [eloquent-relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships) in model..

**Model file**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class <model_name> extends Model
{
    public function <function_name>()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('<namespace_of_target_model>');
    }
}
```

Get JOINED Data in one single query.

```
$data = DB::table('table')
            ->where('column', <condition>)
            ->get();
```

If you didn't set relationship between models than you have to manually JOIN two tables.

**Controller file**

```
$data = DB::table('<table_1>')
        ->leftJoin('<table2>', '<table_1.key>', '<condition>', '<table_2.key>')
        ->get();
```

Here is the [Example](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries) of different types JOIN in Laravel 5.3.

Comment: i am new to laravel.i dont know how to use these mentioned joins

Comment: public function getId($id)
{
$data['detail']=User::find($id); 
return view('new_form',$data);
}

Comment: @deepaksharma which two table's data you want?

Comment: Edit your question and Add User model and message model's code.